# Should we save results in database models which we can anytime calculate using data?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a Report Card Model. I have with me:

```
Question ids, answers selected for each question by candidate, correct answer id of each question, weight of each question.
```

Is it a good idea, to create fields like "**Total marks, average, no of correct answers, number of questions**" etc in my ReportCard model **OR** should I calculate everything , every time a viewer visits the detail view of this report card ?

**My Model so far:**

```
class ReportCard(models.Model):
    exam = models.OneToOneField(Exam)

class ExamChoiceMade(models.Model):
    report_card = models.OneToOneField(ReportCard)
    question_no = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    answer_chosen = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: If it gets so complex that the calculations need too much time do do them every time you need them: yes, otherwise no. If you change a value anywhere, your calculation (average or whatever) will not be correct anymore. Doublesaved information leads to inconsistency.

Comment: Data denormalization is a very intricate topic and I don't think there is an immediate yes/no answer. I, myself am inclined to say yes for efficiency reasons. So you should add and update the total marks for example. Redis is a powerful in-memory caching that would helo you a lot.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't save redundant data, but, it actually depends. How heavy is the processing? How frequently change the data that the calculation depends on? Take into account that if you save the calculation in your model, you have to update the result every time that other depending field change.

Comment: Also, this is not a python/django question, you will face this in any kind of framework or stack that use models and a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that you need to remember is that no matter what decisions you make, there will be trade-offs. And among all the choices you have, you need to consider the best ever option.

In web you mainly need to consider the scalability as the main issue related to performance trade-offs.
It is a good practice to keep lightly calculated (as in non-resource hungry) fields as `model-properties` so that they will act as a field of the tables but never gets stored and is calculated on-demand.
Now when we consider the on-demand calculation if it is resource hungry, your response is going to be very slow. And we should be very careful to keep our response time < 100ms for any normal(even those appears to be normal for end user) actions.

So the answer to you question is that the call on whether to store or calculate on demand is requirement dependant.

However the fileds that you have mentioned above doesn't seem to be resource hungry and so can be just `model property`.

Comment: Also it's useful to remember that there's @cached_property decorator in Django

Comment: Yes! as @Satevg, mentioned using the `@cached_property` of `from django.utils.functional import cached_property`, will avoid the recalculation of the value in as long as the instance is alive. So using the filed in multiple place doesn't need it to be recalculated.